# Meaning of resource_class being NULL

Tags: azure-synapse

I am querying sys.dm_pdw_exec_requests DMV on my Azure SQL DWH. I see that almost all the rows have NULL value in resource_class columns. As per my understanding, every query being run on the system must have a resource_class. Can somebody help me understand as to what does NULL resource_class signify

Answer (score 0):

Null resource_class means it was a statement that isn’t [governed by resource classes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-data-warehouse/resource-classes-for-workload-management?#operations-not-governed-by-resource-classes) such as a DMV query or a CREATE TABLE statement.